# How do I switch between freezing Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 apps using Pyinstaller?

Tags: pyinstaller

I have a script EDS_converter.py written in python 2.7. When I run `pyinstaller EDS_converter.py` the .exe has errors that I can replicate if I try to run my code in python 3.4.

looking at the dist folder sure enough I see `python34.dll` and `pywintypes34.dll`. I use Pyinstaller often in Python 3.4 to freeze a different app. So how do I switch between 3.4 and 2.7 easily?

I have searched for quite a while and read the Pyinstaller docs. I'm amazed there isn't an easy-to-find solution and will delete this question if it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the Python 3 `pyinstaller` path in your `PATH` environment variable.

Assuming that you use the default installation for windows (modify that as appropriate) you can type in the command line:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe EDS_converter.py
```

Alternatively, you can also call the `pyinstaller` script:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py EDS_converter.py
```

I used the full path because chances are that your default `PYTHONPATH` points to your Python 3 installation.

Comment: I'm confused. pyinstaller.exe nor pyinstaller-script.py exist in C:\Python27\Scripts. pyinstaller.exe does exist in the 3.4 folder though. I don't have a PYTHONPATH variable set up looking at my Environment Variables. I have C:\Python27\ , C:\Python27\Scripts and both those for 3.4 in my path variable.

Comment: When I run python in the terminal I get 2.7. I use py -3 to get 3.4

Comment: I used pip (which is 2.7. pip3 for 3.4) to install pyinstaller for 2.7. I must have uninstalled it somehow when I had problems porting code to 3.4 since I've frozen 2.7 apps before. Either way. works now and I'm happy to have all this information in one place now in case this happens again, thanx

Comment: Sorry for not answering your comments. I was away for the weekend. Glad that it is solved.